# Python Eclipse Pipe

Tags: python, eclipse, input, pydev, stdin

### Question

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355721/passing-command-line-argument-to-python-script-within-eclipsepydev) question, I am new to Python.

I have the following simple program running in Eclipse Juno using PyDev - OSX 10.8.1. I want to pass a `stdin` stream. If i were running this in the comand line it would look as follows:

> python main.py < test_input.txt

**How do I go about adding this to the parameters for my eclipse project?**

### Code

```
import sys

def getArgs():
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        for line in sys.stdin:
            print line

def main():
    getArgs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the Common tab of the run configuration for PyDev:

[image]

You can set an **output** file by filling in the `File` box. This will redirect standard output to the file. The `Allocate console` checkbox enables standard input being in the console when running the program. Unfortunately, there is no way to specify a standard **input** file.

Comment: I saw that in another question on stackoverflow... but wanted input - how do you know `no way to specify a standard input file` ?