# How to pass command line argument to python using eclipse

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing command Line argument to Python script within Eclipse(Pydev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355721/passing-command-line-argument-to-python-script-within-eclipsepydev)

I have a python script that contains the following line:

```
reportIP(sys.argv[1])
```

when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand that there is an argument that need to be passed. How can I do this if I am running my code from eclipse after I added PyDev? Please, try to be detailed as much as you can.

Answer (score 3):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355739/1204143 by [Andrew White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278836/andrew-white):

> Click on the play button down arrow in the tool bar -> run configurations -> (double click) Python Run -> Arguments tab on the right hand side.
>
> From there you can fill out the Program Arguments text box.