# run python code in vi editor and passing user input

Tags: python, user-input, vi

I want to run the following code in vi editor:

```
def factorial( n ):
   if n <1:   # base case
       return 1
   else:
       returnNumber = n * factorial( n - 1 )  # recursive call
       print(str(n) + '! = ' + str(returnNumber))
       return returnNumber
```

I want to give a runtime input for the value n while running the program in vi editor. I don't know how to give run time user input for a python program in vi editor. Also wants to know what changes need to be done in the code while running the code in vi editor. Can I have a resolution for this? I am able to run the code but unable to pass the value of n.

I am running this in Putty and I am using Python3.

Answer (score 1):

To run a code from inside vi editor, use this:

```
:!python code.py arg1
```

Using :! from within vi you can run any valid shell command. Furthermore, you can also pass command-line argument (`arg1`) to your python code using this method.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am unable to do this with your suggestion. Can you please help me with more information. I am running this like following:[arindam@n1 lesson]$ :!python fact1.py factorial(4)
:python fact1.py -v factorial(4) fact1.py factorial(4)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[arindam@n1 lesson]$

Comment: @user3068762: You can not directly call a function. Have look at my answer to see what needs to be changed in your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code:

```
import sys

def factorial(n):
    # your function here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factorial(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

When the script file is executed, it is started from `if __name__ == '__main__'` and your `factorial()` is called with the command line argument as a parameter.

Then you can run this script from within vi as described by *hashbrown*, for example:

```
:!python code.py 20
```

PS: You might want to add a line `print(sys.argv)` just before calling your factorial function, just to learn what sys.argv actually contains (why using index `1` and `int()`).

Comment: For e.g. `:!python my.py M=10 N=41`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355721/passing-command-line-argument-to-python-script-within-eclipsepydev/24830122#24830122)