# Bender's decomposition example in CPLEX's Python

Tags: python, cplex, decomposition

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am running "bendersatsp.py" from the examples proposed by CPLEX via eclips. I have only added the path of atsp.dat in main clause where "filename=" is defined. After running that, it seems it executes only for len(sys.argv)=1 and gives me the following results. Do you know what is the problem and why it does not completely run?

```
  Usage:     bendersatsp.py {0|1} [filename]
  0:        Benders' cuts only used as lazy constraints,
            to separate integer infeasible solutions.
  1:        Benders' cuts also used as user cuts,
            to separate fractional infeasible solutions.
  filename: ATSP instance file name.
       File C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1261\cplex\examples/data/atsp.dat used if no name is provided.
```

Comment: Please show the modifications you made to bendersatsp.py.

Comment: @rkersh, I just added the path of file name. The default data is defined in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1261\cplex\examples/data/atsp.dat in my com, so I just put this as a file name in the original  bendersatsp.py. I have not changed the  bendersatsp.py yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0|1 argument is required. For example, you'll need to run the script like so:

```
python bendersatsp.py 0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1261\cplex\examples/data/atsp.dat"
```

Or, assuming you have changed the default `filename` path:

```
python bendersatsp.py 0
```

I've added some comments to the code that parses the command line arguments below to try and make this clear:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # If there are not 1 or 2 arguments then exit (recall that 
    # sys.argv[0] is the program name itself (i.e., "bendersatsp.py")
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 and len(sys.argv) != 3:
        usage()
        sys.exit(-1)
    # If the first argument is not "0" or "1" then exit.
    if sys.argv[1] not in  ["0", "1"]:
        usage()
        sys.exit(-1)
    # Store the second argument in filename if there is one.
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        filename = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        # Otherwise, use the following default.
        filename = "../../../examples/data/atsp.dat"
    # Pass the arguments into the bendersATSP function.
    bendersATSP(sys.argv[1][0], filename)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! I still cannot run the program, even if in command line. Please see the picture that I have added.

Comment: In your screenshot, you're not using the right commands. For example, you need to `cd` into the directory where bendersatsp.py exists. Then, run `c:\Python34\python.exe bendersatsp.py 0`. Don't start the Python interactive before issuing this command.

Comment: @ rkersh thanks, you are right! What about eclipse? How can I run that?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse for Python development, but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355739/1718477) will help.

Comment: $sys.argv = input('Enter command line arguments: ').split()$                      this works for me! Thank you for your help!

Comment: May I ask another question? In my problem, there is no need to check the feasibility cut. We have to only add the optimality cut. Do you know which part of this program should not consider in my case? This method is new for me and I am trying to figure it out. Thanks again

Comment: Does "user callback" refer to optimality cut? I thought is related to feasibility cut as well.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and misread your earlier question. I've deleted my response.

Comment: @ rkersh I have some questions regarding the implementation of this benders method. I am wondering if I can ask you here or by chat. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I recommend that you ask your questions on the IBM developerWorks forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059).